# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in EndlessAdapter in Android

Tags: android

I am getting this exception:

```
06-09 13:14:41.917: E/AndroidRuntime(630): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
06-09 13:14:41.917: E/AndroidRuntime(630): at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
```

I use the following [`EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless):

```
  private class DemoAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {

    private RotateAnimation rotate=null;

    DemoAdapter(ArrayList<Outlets> outletList) {
        super(new OutletListAdapter(VerticalsListActivity.this, outletList));

        rotate=new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                    0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(600);
        rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
      }

    @Override
    protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
      View row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);

      View child=row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

      child.setVisibility(View.GONE);

      child=row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
      child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      child.startAnimation(rotate);

      return(row);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean cacheInBackground() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(isMoreLoading){
            try {   
                if(Project.isFilterEnabled){
                    getDownloadedData = (FetchAndParseData) new FetchAndParseData().execute(Project.searchUrl+"/pageno/"+ ++i);
                }else{
                    getDownloadedData = (FetchAndParseData) new FetchAndParseData().execute(UrlConstants.OUTLETS_INFO_URL+Project.currentCityId+"/pageno/"+ ++i+"/verticalid/1");
                }
                inputStream = getDownloadedData.get();
                XmlUtilities.parseAndLoadData(inputStream , mOutletXmlHandler);
                outletList = Project.getOutletList();//Project.getOutletList();




            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }               
        return isMoreLoading;
    }

    @Override
    protected void appendCachedData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        adptr = (OutletListAdapter) getWrappedAdapter();
        if(outletList.size()==20){
            isMoreLoading=true;
        }else{
            isMoreLoading=false;
        }           

        if(outletList!=null){
            for (Outlets addThis : outletList) {
                adptr.add(addThis);
            }
        }

    }

  }
```

Now, when a list contains less than 20 elements and we scroll that list it throws mentioned exception. Whats am I doing wrong?

Comment: add full code for outlets ArrayList

Comment: @SamirMangroliya i have added full source code of the class , please help me..

Answer (score 4):

Arun,

ConcurrentModificationException occurs when a collection is being modified by multiple threads. Your `cacheInBackground()` leads me to believe that you are indeed utilizing additional threads to get your data. Most often this occurs when you are adding or removing from the collection (such as caching) at the same time as altering the collection (such as sorting).

The easiest way to solve this is to copy the collection before modifying it in another thread (fetching). After modification is complete, copy the new set and get rid of the old set. This allows you to change the current set as you need (in the background), but make UI changes as necessary while maintaining response.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Fuzzical logic . Thanks for your wonderful answer, its helped me a lot. and i get rid of it.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it helped. Remember, if an answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept it. If it was particularly useful, upvote it. We are a community that thrives on reputable information. :)